# How to find the next element using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
browser.find_element(By.ID,'thread-0-list')
                browser.find_element(By.ID,'tpz_body')
                browser.find_element(By.ID,'view')
                browser.find_element(By.ID,'topaz')
                browser.find_element(By.ID,'X1')
                browser.find_element('id','X4')
                browser.find_element('id','X7') 
                browser.find_element('id','X9') -- empty elements
```

[image: 'X9' inside the 'X4' but return emtpy][image: empty elements from X1Container]
I would like say thank you for your support.
The child div are return empty
how to check next available element using selenium python

[image: next element showing empty object]

```
browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='X7']") --- find the element but 

browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='X9']") -- empty element
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me assume that you want to find the element with id "x7Border" first and then its next sibling next say "x8Border":

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("<URL>")
mydiv = driver.find_element(By.ID,"x7Border")
l=mydiv.find_elements(By.XPATH, "following-sibling::*[1]")
print(l)
```

If you want to find all the sibilings of "x7Border", then,

```
l=mydiv.find_elements(By.XPATH, "following-sibling::*")
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
# Get the div element you are interested in
mydiv = driver.find_element(By.ID, '"x7Border')

# Get next sibling of mydiv
next_sibling = mydiv.find_element(By.XPATH, "following-sibling::*[1]")
print(next_sibling.get_attribute('outerHTML'))
```